# Unable to launch evince

Tags: evince, apparmor, overlayfs

When launching evince, I get this error:

```
EvinceDocument-WARNING **: 10:14:16.337: Error opening directory “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/evince/4/backends”: Permission denied
```

I have already put evince in complain mode, so I think:

```
aa-complain /usr/bin/evince

systemctl restart apparmor
```

Status shows evince is in complain mode:

```
apparmor_status

22 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/bin/evince
```

I am running Ubuntu with overlayfs root.  I have also tried stopping apparmor altogether.

I can do ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/evince/4/backends and see the files just fine.  If I run strace evince, I see the exact same output, that is cannot open that directory.

1. How can I fix that?
2. If it is a fatal error, why is evince logging it as a warning?
3. If apparmor is permitting access (as evidence in dmesg output (ALLOW)), why is it still complaining?

EDIT: #1

```
1. Ubuntu 19.10 Server as a base (not as a install, nor a debootstrap, but close to a debootstrap)
2. xorg + i3 tiling wm installed
3. no virtualization
4. most other applications work as expected
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. temporarily disabling the evince apparmor profile: `apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`
2. permanently disabling the evince apparmor profile by symlinking `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince via /etc/apparmor.d/disable`

Comment: I get `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince: command not found` (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Thanks. Worked on Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to reinstall the Evince packages first with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libevdocument3-4 evince-hwp evince
```

and then retry.

Comment: I just tried that, no luck.