# How to modify Firefox's AppArmor profile to allow evince to open links

Tags: permissions, firefox, evince, apparmor

When I try to open a link from a PDF using Evince I get an error message in the terminal.

> env: ‘/snap/bin/firefox’: Permission denied

It used to work when Firefox wasn't a snap package.

I think the problem might be in Firefox's AppArmor profile, but I am not sure, and don't know how to modify the file to allow evince to open links.

Comment: See this question and answer: [How to open Zoom meeting link in Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410174/how-to-open-zoom-meeting-link-in-firefox-in-ubuntu-22-04) for a similar problem. This is not an AppArmor problem. This is a snap feature.

Comment: Thanks @user68186. The question was useful. It looks like to get it to work, I will have to uninstall the snap version and install a different one.

Comment: You may also use the Firefox's internal PDF viewer: **Open in Firefox**.

Comment: This is not a real answer but rather a workaround: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398523) it is suggested to Evince's apparmor profile entirely to fix the issue. I guess it is safer to remove apparmor from Evince than from Firefox, since I imagine the browser to be a greater malware vector, but still the best solution would be fixing the profile, and I don't know how to do that either. Let us hope a more knowledgeable user sees this question now that I have bumped it with a workaround answer and added a bounty.

Comment: A workaround is to replace the snap version of Firefox with the .deb version. https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466